# My pure CSS dropdown isn't working, anybody knows how to fix it?

Tags: css, dropdown

I'm a CSS starter and my pure CSS dropdown isn't working.

Example in this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uevewfsy/

I've been looking around on internet and trying to fix it myself but I have tried countless things and it still isn't fixed. Having a float: left; on the primary ul seems to fix it, but then my nav isn't centered anymore.

Hope someone can help me so I can go further with programming again ;)

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

h1 {
    font-weight: 100;
}

.nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
    background-color: #333;
    text-align: center;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 150;
}

.nav ul {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.nav > ul > li {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 20px 0 20px;
}

.nav > ul > li:first-child > a:after {
    width: 6px;
    height: 6px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
    border-right: 1px solid white;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: calc(5vh - 5px);
    margin-left: 8px;
    content: "";
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.nav > ul > li > ul {
    display: none;
}

.nav > ul > li > ul > li {
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #333;
    padding: 0 15px 0 15px;
}

.nav li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}

.nav ul a {
    color: #A3ABA3;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 10vh;
}

.nav a:hover {
    color: #FFF;
}

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px){
    
}
```

```html
<body>
   <div class="nav">
       <ul>
           <li>
               <a href="#">PAGE</a>
               <ul>
                   <li><a href="#">DROPDOWN</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">DROPDOWN</a></li>
               </ul>
           </li>
           <li><a href="#">PAGE</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">PAGE</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">PAGE</a></li>
       </ul>
   </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are just missing `vertical-align:top` in your `nav > ul > li`,

you can add `position:relative/top` to your `li/ul` as well.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
h1 {
  font-weight: 100;
}
.nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10%;
  background-color: #333;
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 150;
}
.nav ul {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.nav > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0 20px;
  vertical-align: top
}
.nav > ul > li:first-child > a:after {
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  border-right: 1px solid white;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: calc(5vh - 5px);
  margin-left: 8px;
  content: "";
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.nav > ul > li > ul {
  display: none;
}
.nav > ul > li > ul > li {
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #333;
  padding: 0 15px;
  position:relative
}
.nav li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
  position:absolute;
  top:100%;
  width:30%
    
  
}
.nav ul a {
  color: #A3ABA3;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 10vh;
}
.nav a:hover {
  color: #FFF;
}
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="nav">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">PAGE</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">DROPDOWN</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">DROPDOWN</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">PAGE</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">PAGE</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">PAGE</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```